# Ucwords doesn't work on new line.. alternative?

Tags: php

PHP `ucwords()` does not work on data on a new line, for example:

```
hello
world
```

Would output as

```
Hello
world
```

as it counts both words as one word, even though they are on a new line

How can I get it to upper case each word, even if its on a new line and does not have a space between them?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this, but for me it works. Could it be there is some content between the two words that is not displayed in the browser? (such a <br /> tag) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is strange. the function uses any white space, including new line characters, as space netween words. is this an html br or a actual newline character?

an alternative function you could try is mb_convert_case()

also, if the new line is made by html, you could try something like this.

```
nl2br(ucwords(str_replace('<br />', "\n", $input)))
```